# Show current audio amplitude in textview

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I think I am fairly close to achieving what I need to, but I'm getting an error when trying to convert my current amplitude integer into a string in a textview.

So my aim is this: Display a camera preview (working), detect sound (possibly working) and display the current amplitude level of that sound in a textview (textPowerUp). Later I want to replace the textview with a counter that counts up when sound is detected, and slowly counts back down when it's not, but baby steps...

So no errors if I comment out the line:

```
txtPowerLevel.setText(Integer.toString(currentAmplitude));
```

But that's the line I'm -trying- to use to convert the amplitude integer into a string and insert it into my textview. And this line gives a null reference error.

I even tried to force the currentAmplitude to have a value of at least 0 with:

```
if (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() > 0) {
    currentAmplitude = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
} else {
    currentAmplitude = 0;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to help. I still get a null reference error. I even tried setting the else to a value of '1' incase '0' was being seen as 'null' but no luck there either.

Here's the entire class... please let me know if you can spot the problem!

```
public class DBZPowerUp extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Camera mCamera;
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private int currentAmplitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dbzpowerup);

        // Variables for textureview
        mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        // Build the camera preview onto textureview
        setContentView(mTextureView);

        // Run methods to start audio capture
        startAudioCapture();
        getAmplitude();

        // Repeat audio methods constantly
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

        // Input the current amplitude level into the power level textview
        setCurrentAmplitude();
        TextView txtPowerLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPowerLevel);
        txtPowerLevel.setText(Integer.toString(currentAmplitude));

    }

    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("DBZ_", "Camera broke");
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // Ignored, Camera does all the work for us
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        stopAudioCapture();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        // Invoked every time there's a new Camera preview frame
    }

    public void startAudioCapture() {
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mRecorder.start();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    public void stopAudioCapture() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null)
            return  mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        else
            return 0;

    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */
            getAmplitude();
      /* and here comes the "trick" */
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    private void setCurrentAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() > 0) {
            currentAmplitude = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        } else {
            currentAmplitude = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And thanks so much in advanced!

Lee.

ANSWER (Thanks to Blackbelt):

I changed:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dbzpowerup);

        // Variables for textureview
        mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        // Build the camera preview onto textureview
        setContentView(mTextureView);
```

To:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dbzpowerup);

        // Define the textureview in XML and apply the surface listener for camera preview
        TextureView mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView1);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your NPE is due to

```
// Build the camera preview onto textureview
setContentView(mTextureView);
```

this way you are overriding  he previous call to `setContentView` which   probably contains your `TextView`. You could add the `TextureView` to `dbzpowerup.xml` and use `findViewById` to grab a reference to it

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you so much! If anyone else has this issue, I have added the resolution to my original question.